# Problem during install Ubuntu 14.04, 14.04.1 and 14.04.2 on HP DL360p Gen8

Tags: 14.04, networking, server, network-manager, hp

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 14.04.1 on a HP Proliant DL360p Gen8 with 2 HP Network card 560SFP+ (one onboard and one PCI-E).

When network configuration comes up, no DHCP is found even if there is one on the network.

I looked in the console screen and saw this :

```
> netcfg[12341]: INFO : Starting netcfg v.1.116ubuntu1 (built 20140403-1424)
> netcfg[12341]: WARNING **: Couldn't read Wpasupplicant pid file, not trying to kill.
> netcfg[12341]: DEBUG: Flushing addresses and routes on interface: em1
> netcfg[12341]: DEBUG: Flushing addresses and routes on interface: em2
> netcfg[12341]: DEBUG: Flushing addresses and routes on interface: p2p1
> netcfg[12341]: DEBUG: Flushing addresses and routes on interface: p2p2
> netcfg[12341]: INFO : Could not find valid BOOTIF= entry in /proc/cmdline
> netcfg[12341]: INFO : taking down interface em1
> netcfg[12341]: INFO : taking down interface em2
> netcfg[12341]: INFO : taking down interface p2p1
> netcfg[12341]: INFO : taking down interface p2p2
```

Before starting installation network link is UP.

I have the `same problem with Ubuntu 14.04.2 (netcfg v.1.116ubuntu2)`

Can you help me ?

Regards,
Jerome

Answer (score 0):

The problem is resolved. Even if there is this message, the networt card are available after the installation.

Sorry to have bothered you for nothing

Regards,
Jerome